# Return information schema column comments into a php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, information-schema

The follwing shows how to output an individual table column comment.

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xyz") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database",$db) or die(mysql_error()); 

function table_description($t,$c,$d){ 
     $sql = "SELECT column_comment FROM information_schema.columns  
      WHERE table_name = '$t' AND column_name LIKE '$c'"; 
     $query = mysql_query($sql,$d) or die(mysql_error()); 
     $v = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
     if($v){ 
         return $v[0]; 
         } 
     return 'Table description not found'; 
     } 

echo table_description('table','col',$db);
```

However I would like table_description to return an array of every column comment in that table.
e.g. Column_Name, Column_Comments (so "RecID" => "ID of the record") etc.
I have little experience of working with php arrays/ converting resultsets to array.

Answer (score 1):

loop through the query results with a `while` loop, store the results in an array outside of the scope of the `while` loop...

for example:

```
function table_description($t,$c,$d){
     $t = mysql_real_escape_string($t); //prevent sql injection
     $c = mysql_real_escape_string($c);

     $sql = "SELECT column_comment,column_name FROM information_schema.columns  
      WHERE table_name = '$t' AND column_name LIKE '$c'"; 
     $query = mysql_query($sql,$d) or die(mysql_error());
     $columnArray = array();

     while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){


       $columnArray[] = array('column_comment' => $result['column_comment'], 'column_name' => $result['column_name']);

     }

    return $columnArray;
}
```

`$columnArray[0]['column_name']` would return the column name of the first element of the array $columnArray

Comment: that looks good, I'll test it later. How would I return the column_comment by specifying a specific field title. So would echo $columnArray('RecID') output "The ID of the record" ?

Comment: Will there be more than one query result?

Comment: I am expecting the code you have given to give me an array of multiple results

Comment: Ah, I see the original code would not have done what I was after now. I still need to be able to return the column_comment based on the column_name. so If I do.. $columnArray('RecID') it will output the associated column_comment which would be "The ID of the record". And then the $columnArray('EmailAdd') would return "The email address entered by the user" etc. Would it just be 
`$columnArray[] =  array($result['Column_Name'] => $result['column_comment']);`